# Node JS FREEZES when _.template is evaluated and a ReferenceError happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I've found a weird behavior with http://underscorejs.org/ in Node JS:

When a reference error happens when we evaluate a template function, Node JS will FREEZE!

Examples:

**EXAMPLE 1: HAPPY DAY SCENARIO:**

```
var template = "<%= test %>";
var compiledTemplate = _.template(template);
var result = compiledTemplate({test:1});
console.log(result);

//RESULT (both BROWSER and NODE JS):
//1
```

**EXAMPLE 2: COMPILE ERROR SCENARIO (an extra = before closing):**

```
var template = "<%= test =%>";
var compiledTemplate = _.template(template);
var result = compiledTemplate({test:1});
console.log(result);

//RESULT (both BROWSER and NODE JS):
//uncaughtException { [SyntaxError: Unexpected token )]
```

**EXAMPLE 3: EVALUATION ERROR SCENARIO (test is not defined):**

```
var template = "<%= test %>";
var compiledTemplate = _.template(template);
var result = compiledTemplate({no_test_defined:1});
console.log(result);

//RESULT (BROWSER):
//Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
//RESULT (NODE JS):
//Node JS FREEZES - nothing happens, neither and error is thrown, neither the flow goes on
```

Anybody had ever get a similar behavior? Any hints for solution? I really need to catch the exception in a try/catch block...

Cheers!

Oscar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some troubleshoot I could finally found what was the problem.

When I run this inside Webstorm DEBUGGER, this behavior happens (Node JS FREEZES). When I run it in command line, i works as expected. I will search in Webstorm issues if hey have something.

Cheers!!!!

Oscar